# Is it possible to use oData filtering, sorting, paging in regular WCF serivce?

Tags: wcf, odata, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a web service which supports filtering. sorting and paging. I had a look at WCF oData service. It has all these features and requires minimum setup. However, I don't think you can write business logic in the service and so oData is only good for read only services (and may be for read write services where no business logic is involved).

Later I had a look at MVC Web API which supports oData style filtering, etc. just by using the return type for the method as IQueryable. I was happy after knowing this until I found that you cannot automatically generate client code for the service. I don't want to deal with the HTTP stuff. I need the client to be generated automatically.

So I want to know whether the same IQueryable thing would work in a regular WCF service as it supports automatic client generation.

Answer (score 0):

If the asp.net MVC app has a $metadata end point then you can use the existing Microsoft.Data.Services.Client to access this service. You can create the client code using Add Service Reference in Vistual Studio by giving the $metadata endpoint. It will then create a client layer that you use to access the service.

Attached is a link to a blog post on an OData Service using ASP.net MVC.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/12/07/odata-in-webapi-rc-release.aspx

To create a client layer you can follow the walkthrough here by skipping to the "Creating the Client Application" heading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668184.aspx

You can do filtering, paging (client and server paging) with ASP.net MVC with OData.